# Let $(\Omega,F)$ be a measurable space, $F=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$, prove that $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ is a random variable iff $X$ is constant.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,F)$ be a measurable space, $F=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ prove that $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ is a random variable if and only if $X$ is constant.

I was thinking this is not necessarily true as if

$$X(\varnothing) \to 0$$
$$X(\omega_i) \to a_i, a_i \in R, a_i \neq 0$$
$X$ will still be measurable and a random variable but not a constant, right? since ${0}$ and ${a_i} \in B(R)$.

Comment: What is the probability space in this example? Is the empty set an element of it?

Comment: @Mark F={∅,Ω}, X:Ω→R

Comment: When is X measurable?

Comment: @Al.G. F is a sigma algebra, B(R) also a sigma algebra, so X:F->R means X is measurable?

Comment: @TJT But what is $\Omega$ in your example? Also, your definition of a random variable (from the last comment) is wrong. A random variable is a function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for any set $B\in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$, the inverse image $X^{-1}(B)$ belongs to the sigma algebra $F$.

Comment: @Mark sorry, I should type with more care, what I meant was X(A)->B, A $\in$ F, B $\in$ B(R), isn't this the same as what you have, and does it matter what $\Omega$ is?

Comment: Your proposed function is not measurable

Comment: @Andrew Hi, Andrew, could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: With some abuse of notation, the preimage of $a_i$ is $\omega_i$. But that’s not in $\mathcal F$, so it’s not measurable.

Comment: @Andrew thanks, I see it now

Comment: @Andrew so if I let $X(\varnothing) = 0$, then the pre-image of empty set is not in $\mathcal F$ right? which also makes it not measurable

Comment: $X$ is a function on $\Omega$. Its argument should be an element of $\Omega$, not a set. What does $X(\emptyset)$ mean?

Comment: $\Omega$ could contain the empty set…but you need to clarify

Answer (score 2):

"=>" Suppose by contradiction that $X$ is not constant. That is, there exist $\omega_1,\omega_2\in\Omega$ s.t. $X(\omega_1)\neq X(\omega_2).$ Consider the Borel set $A:=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{X(\omega_1)\}$ then neither $X^{-1}(A)=\Omega$ nor $X^{-1}(A)=\varnothing$. This fact contradicts the $\mathcal{F}$-measurability of $X$.

"<=" Suppose that $X$ is constant, i.e. $X(\omega)=c\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$. Let $A$ be a Borel set. If $c\in A$, $X^{-1}(A)=\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$. If $c\notin A$, $X^{-1}(A)=\varnothing\in\mathcal{F}.$ Thus, $X$ is measurable.

Note that "<=" is true for any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$.